# Sugarcrm cssClass for Subpanel field status based color not working

Tags: php, jquery, backbone.js, sugarcrm

I am trying to add CSS class using a handlebars template in SugarCrm 7.x, I am facing issue `this.cssClass` is undefined, But the same was working for the modules. Not sure whats the issue here. Following is my Code:

```
({
    extendsFrom: 'EnumField',

    /**
     * Initializes the view
     *
     * @param options
     */
    initialize: function (options) {
        this._super('initialize', [options]);
        this.collection.on('data:sync:complete', function () {
            this.renderRules();
        }, this);
    },

    /**
     * Set background color for sales_stage
     */
    renderRules: function () {

        var colourMap = {
            "Lost" : "red",
            "Won" : "green",
        };

        var statusValue =  this.model.get('sales_stage');
        this.cssClass = 'label ' + colourMap[statusValue];
    }
});
```

I do understand that I can achieve the solution using the following jquery, But I am trying to understand why `this.cssClass` is undefined only in this particular place.

```
$('div[title="'+statusValue+'"]').addClass('label '+colourMap[statusValue]);
$('div[data-original-title="'+statusValue+'"]').addClass('label '+colourMap[statusValue]);
```

Comment: just a guess, but assuming `this.cssClass` is fed into the handlebars template, the chances are that the template is rendered before the collection syncs. As you state, fixing the class value in the already rendered HTML works, because it's modifying after the render.

Comment: yup! solved it.. will update the answer in few days..